# How to use numeric function in sequelize(Like Round)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my database (like XXX) and table name is "user"

the user table has four column

```
*-----*------*---------*--------*
|  ID | NAME |  STATUS |  DEBT  |
*-----*------*---------*--------*
```

I want to update DEBT in the user table with the round function

raw query like

```
"UPDATE users SET DEBT = ROUND(getDebt, 2) WHERE ID = ?"
```

How to the use round function in sequelize?

Answer (score 2):

example of use mysql function in sequelize (use **sequelize.fn** )

```
  models.post.findAll({
    include: [
         {
          model: models.review,
          //    select attributes
          attributes: [
            [models.sequelize.fn('avg', models.sequelize.col('stars')), 'rating'],
            [models.sequelize.fn('count', '*'), 'count']
          ],
        }
        ]
    })
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
```

more info http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn